# find count of images within a directory

Tags: linux, bash, find

I wanted to find the number of image files within a directory. I ended up using this :

```
find . -type f  -exec file {} \; | grep -c -i 'image'
```

This feels like an inefficient way of doing it. I could think of another way to do it - using an OR statement, but I couldn't figure out from the man page how this could be done.

Any ideas how this could be done more efficiently? I don't want to execute the commands above on a directory with a rather large number of files and have it take forever.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search for images by extension, you can use the following command:

```
find -type f -name *.gif -o -name *.jpg -o -name *.bmp
```

Of course, you need to list all extensions you are interested in.

To get the count, you can append `| wc -l`.

Comment: It's better to use `-iname` to match case insensitive

Answer (score 5):

You can get an efficiency improvement by using `\+` instead of `\;`.  The difference here is that `\+` passes all found files to a single execution of `file` where `\;` executes `file` once for every file that was found.

```
find . -type f  -exec file {} \+ | grep -c -i 'image'
```

You will run into problems if it finds more files than `file` can take as arguments.  You could pipe it through `xargs` with the `--max-args` option if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find files by mime-type of file in this case "image", you will need following command

```
   find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | grep -i image | wc -l
```

Comment: He's already got it working.  He's asking for a more efficient method.  I suspect the `find | xargs` pattern *is* probably more efficient since it will only invoke `file` once where the original method invokes it once for every file found.  `grep -ci image` would be more efficient than `grep -i image | wc -l`.